# how to assign a value of a query to a variable in zend

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, sum, mysql-num-rows

I need to calculate the average from a mysql table. So I am taking the sum of a col and dividing it by the number of rows. But the values are not being assigned properly :-

```
$total_sum_query = $db->query("SELECT SUM(marks) FROM markstable WHERE sid = '$sid'");
$num_rows_query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM markstable WHERE sid = '$sid'");

$avg_marks = $total_sum_query/$num_rows_query;
```

I know i am doing something wrong but can not figure it out. Is there a way to derive the average in mysql?

Comment: Try the [MySQL `AVG()` command](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)

Answer (score 1):

What you actually want is:

```
$avg_marks = $db->fetchOne("SELECT AVG(marks) FROM markstable WHERE sid = ?", $sid);
```

fetchOne gives you a single value instead of a result set or array, and use parameterised queries to protect against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$num_rows_query = $db->query("SELECT count(*) as cnt FROM markstable WHERE sid = '$sid'");
```

and use it as $num_rows_query['cnt'];

or you can directly try like

```
$avg_query =  $db->query("SELECT AVG(marks) FROM markstable WHERE sid = '$sid'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [AVG in MYSL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg)

```
$average_query =  $db->query("SELECT AVG(marks) FROM markstable WHERE sid = '$sid'");
```